# MySQL. Start new row in case of end of month

Tags: mysql, date, intervals, talend

I was wondering if there is any way to solve this.

So my row has an column of type date which increments with 1 day daily ( untill the end of the respective month ). At the beggining of a new month a new row has to be generated and the update will start again untill the and of that month, and so on..

Comment: What causes the date to increment daily?

Comment: How do you create that initial row? I guess you have to catch that in your programming language rather than in sql.

Comment: Hello, I am using an ETL, Talend. In an tMysqlInput I have an CURDATE() function which increments it daily because the job is programmed to run every night.

Comment: I guess you need to amend your function to recognise that it needs to insert rather than update when a new month is encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to think about the problem in MySQL's dialect of SQL.

First, you need a function that changes a `datestamp` into a value that's unique for each month.  That is `LAST_DAY(datestamp)`.  It generates `DATETIME` values like `2017-09-30 00:00:00` from arbitrary inputs.

Next, you can exploit MySQL's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` capability. You will create a table `months` with, say, these columns

```
   month_ending DATETIME
   category     VARCHAR(20)
   sum_of_input INT
```

Then you make `month_ending, category` into a unique compound index.

Then you do something like this

```
 INSERT INTO months                    /* warning! not debugged! */
        (month_ending, category, sum_of_input)
 VALUES (LAST_DAY(?date), ?category, ?value)
 ON DUPLICATE KEY 
 UPDATE months
    SET sum_of_input = sum_of_input + ?value
  WHERE month_ending=LAST_DAY(?date) 
    AND category=?category
```

However, this has the hallmarks of a big, hard to debug, pain in the neck. It make make more sense to use features inside your ETL system to do this summarizing work.